# separate swagger UI URLs for ASPNETCORE 1.1

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, asp.net-core-webapi, swashbuckle

We have a .NET core 1.1 webapi project. We have two controller files and I've been able to generate separate swagger JSON files for each controller by decorating methods with GroupName.

When I browser the swagger UI (/swagger) I see that it has a drop down on top right corner that allows us to select the group.

Our requirement is to have a separate URL itself for swagger UI (not just JSON file) so that we can send a URL dedicated to a controller to our customers that doesn't confuse them. Is there a way to tell swashbuckle/swagger UI to use a specific URL for given JSON file/group name?

I tried checking if there's any query string parameter that swagger UI uses on change of dropdown but unfortunately it uses referer http header...

Answer (score 0):

Yes swagger-ui has the url param that does exactly that.

Here are a few examples:

- http://petstore.swagger.io/?url=http://heldersepu.github.io/hs-scripts/swagger/4134_swagger.json
- http://offleaseonly.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index?url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oasis-tcs/odata-openapi/master/examples/People.openapi3.json
- http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index?url=http://heldersepu.github.io/hs-scripts/swagger/DiegoGuidi.json

Comment: Do you mean to say I should be able to do something like this?

http://<mywebsite>/swagger/?url=http://<mywebsite>.abc.jsonfile.json

Or I have to use petstore.swagger.io?

I know the url parameter did not work when using localhost

Comment: Correct you can use yours or any other, not sure why it did not work on localhost...